# searching for a date timestamp greater than a specific value using awk command returns more matches

Tags: awk, grep

I am trying to filter logs entries which are newer/greater than a specific date timestamp which is stored in a lastrun.txt file. But it is giving more matches/result when I read the timestamp from a file.

```
$ cat lastrun.txt

2021-03-12 00:48:27.482


command:

grep 2021-03-12  data.log | awk '$0 > "$(cat lastrun.txt)"'

output:
2021-03-12 00:10:10.891 GMT uuid="e6a1170a-b745-4861-b769-383787b18c92"
2021-03-12 00:46:17.378 GMT uuid="3a8178be-4cd3-4f98-8628-7bdd8380751a"
2021-03-12 00:48:27.482 GMT uuid="42ed7b81-8db8-4d68-9c85-1d56565ca970"
2021-03-12 01:04:15.624 GMT uuid="219963ab-d81d-4fd7-9003-83d20700a5ba"
2021-03-12 01:18:22.822 GMT uuid="5f4f63a3-a23c-4bd7-9041-75d7ee30f07a"

In the above output, I am getting first two lines which should not appear because the timestamp in those two lines are less than the search pattern (2021-03-12 00:48:27.482)

Please help with this.
```

Comment: All output lines are `2021-03-12` which matches the `grep 2021-03-12` ?? You have no time comparison specified -- this that way you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand and you want to output entries in your log where both the date and time are greater than contained in `lastrun.txt`, then you will need to convert both the date and time from `lastrun.txt` to numeric values and compare with the converted date and time in each record of the log. Thankfully the timestmps in POSIX format make that easy to do in `awk` by simply removing the delimiters from each.

You do not need any other utility than `awk` and you can simply specify both files as arguments to `awk` and call it once. You read the first record from `lastrun.txt` and save the converted date and time (in `dt` and `tm` below). Then using the fact that `NR` (total number of records processed) will not equal `FNR` (file record number) for the second file, you can easily only make the comparison on the second file. You can use two rules as follows:

```
awk '
    NR==1 {dt=$1; gsub(/-/,"",dt); tm=$2; gsub(/[:.]/,"",tm); tm+=0} 
    NR!=FNR {rec=$0; gsub(/-/,"",$1); gsub(/[:.]/,"",$2); $2+=0; if($1>=dt && $2>=tm)print rec}
' lastrun.txt log
```

Where the files `lastrun.txt` is as you show, and `log` contains:

```
2021-03-12 00:10:10.891 GMT uuid="e6a1170a-b745-4861-b769-383787b18c92"
2021-03-12 00:46:17.378 GMT uuid="3a8178be-4cd3-4f98-8628-7bdd8380751a"
2021-03-12 00:48:27.482 GMT uuid="42ed7b81-8db8-4d68-9c85-1d56565ca970"
2021-03-12 01:04:15.624 GMT uuid="219963ab-d81d-4fd7-9003-83d20700a5ba"
2021-03-12 01:18:22.822 GMT uuid="5f4f63a3-a23c-4bd7-9041-75d7ee30f07a"
```

**Example Use/Output**

Running the command above (you can just select-copy and middle-mouse-paste into an xterm with both files in the current directory), you would get

```
2021-03-12 00:48:27.482 GMT uuid="42ed7b81-8db8-4d68-9c85-1d56565ca970"
2021-03-12 01:04:15.624 GMT uuid="219963ab-d81d-4fd7-9003-83d20700a5ba"
2021-03-12 01:18:22.822 GMT uuid="5f4f63a3-a23c-4bd7-9041-75d7ee30f07a"
```

Which is what I believe you indicate wanting.

**Formatted With Full Indentation**

Writing it out in an expanded format may help you follow along. Formatted with full indention, you would have:

```
awk '
    NR == 1 {                          # first file 1st record, save dt & tm
        dt = $1
        gsub (/-/,"",dt)               # remove '-' from date
        tm = $2
        gsub (/[:.]/,"",tm)            # remove ':' and '.' from time
        tm += 0                        # add zero to force as number removing leading 0s
    }
    NR != FNR {                        # second file, convert and compare with dt & tm
        rec = $0                       # save record before modifying $1 & $2
        gsub (/-/,"",$1)               # same removals and + 0
        gsub (/[:.]/,"",$2)
        $2 += 0
        if ($1 >= dt && $2 >= tm)      # compare to original dt & tm
            print rec                  # print saved record if greater
    }
' lastrun.txt log
```

**Only Dates & Time Larger `lastrun.txt` Time**

If that is the case, then simply changing the `$2 > tm` comparison will do, e.g.

```
        if ($1 >= dt && $2 > tm)       # compare to original dt & tm
```

Drops the first output record as the times are equal, so the output for only greater than time would be:

```
2021-03-12 01:04:15.624 GMT uuid="219963ab-d81d-4fd7-9003-83d20700a5ba"
2021-03-12 01:18:22.822 GMT uuid="5f4f63a3-a23c-4bd7-9041-75d7ee30f07a"
```

Is that the beginning of the output your want?

Look things over and let me know if that is what you needed or if you have further questions.

Comment: Thank you David. It works. However, it is also including the record having the search date timestamp (2021-03-12 00:48:27.482) even when I tried with if ($1>dt && $2>tm). Basically I am trying to filter/fetch the records which are greater than the date timestamp defined in the lastrun.txt file.

Comment: If you only want records where the date is larger than `2021-03-12 00:48:27.482` then why wont `if ($1 >= dt && $2 > tm)` work? Or do you only want to start on `2021-03-13`?

Comment: Greetings @DavidC.Rankin. I have learnt a lot from you and I request your support on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/406140/11096022 when you have a minute

Comment: @ronythomas Done. Excellent post on Meta.